# How many types of tickets must be printed so that a person can choose to travel between any of the two stations?

Tags: combinatorics, discrete-mathematics, combinations

There are $13$ stations between Chennai and Coimbatore.  How many types of tickets must be printed so that a person can choose to travel between any of the two stations?

Comment: $\dbinom{13}{2}$

Comment: @InterstellarProbe I agree with your methodology, is there a problem with mine? Why are we getting different answers?

Comment: @RayDansh You seem to be assuming that the stations are ordered in a circular fashion and that one cannot go from one station to the next or the previous. I made no such assumption. I also did not assume that one would want to travel to or from Chennai or Coimbatore. If we add those in, it is $\dbinom{15}{2}$.

Comment: @MikhailHogrefe Thank you for the explanation! I will edit my answer immediately.

Comment: This isn't a place for yo to dump your homework, explain your thoughts first.

Comment: The last time I had a train ticket it was good for travel in only one direction, from point A to point B (but not from point B back to point A). On the other hand, is one allowed to get off before the destination on one's ticket? The policy might be that one may, but then the ticket cannot be used to continue to the destination. (But the policy might be otherwise: airlines can get very punitive if you choose not to travel all the way to the destination you were booked for.)

Comment: A reason this is not a well-posed problem is that it refers to a possible real-world scenario (traveling by train) which in the real world could be subject to any of several policies depending on the desire of that railway line; and the question does not adequately describe what relevant policies are in force.

Answer (score 0):

This is similar to finding the diagonals of a tridecagon (13-sided polygon). The formula is $$\frac{n(n-3)}2$$

Plugging in $13$, we get $65$ different tickets.

EDIT: I forgot to consider going around the edge of the tridecagon itself, which gives us $13$ more tickets, or a total of $78$ tickets.

The above method was simply for visualization. Another way is simply to take ${13 \choose 2}$, or the ways in which you can choose two locations out of a total of thirteen locations. This will also give you $78$.